# How can I navigate children in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database. I have some keys in the root. And I have keys and children within these keys. I need to listen to the values of a specific child. For example, the structure is like this:

```
root
├── d775810
│   ├── datas_for_type
│   │   └── timestamp
│   │       └── multiple list datas  
│   └── reportFlag 
│       └── timestamp
│           └── flagAnnotation:True
└── a413ba21
    ├── datas_for_type
    │   └── timestamp
    │       └── multiple list datas 
    └── reportFlag 
        └── timestamp
            └── flagAnnotation:False
```

I need to listen to the "flagAnnotation" child. If it is true, I will access the data with the same timestamp and create a PDF. How can I listen to the values of this child?

I tried this:

```
dbRef.ref().on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
    console.log(`Child added: ${snapshot.key}`);
});
```

This give only d775810,a413ba21.. and if ı add root, ıt will give them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database reads always return full nodes. This means that you can't listen for just the `flagAnnotation` properties.

You *can* listen for the entire JSON branch however, and then navigate the data snapshot you get to just show the `flagAnnotation` values.

```
firebase.database().ref().get('value').then((rootSnapshot) => {
  rootSnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    console.log(childSnapshot.val().reportFlag.timestamp.flagAnnotation);
  });
})
```

If the `timestamp` in your JSON is dynamic, you'll need another `forEach` to loop over those children, and it'd become:

```
firebase.database().ref().get('value').then((rootSnapshot) => {
  rootSnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const reportFlagSnapshot = childSnapshot.child('reportFlag');
    reportFlagSnapshot.forEach((timestampSnapshot) => {
      console.log(timestampSnapshot.key, timestampSnapshot.val().flagAnnotation);
    })
  });
})
```